# http status code to signal an instance that is part of an ELB is unhealthy

Tags: rest, http, amazon-elb

As per https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/using-features.healthstatus.html the web service should respond with `200 OK` HTTP status code to signal a healthy application or **any other one** for unhealthy.

**My questions is which HTTP status is most appropriate for an unhealthy application?**

Out of all HTTP status classes below

- `1xx Informational response`
- `2xx Success`
- `3xx Redirection`
- `4xx Client errors`
- `5xx Server errors`

simple logic suggests it should be a server error other than anything else and out of all the `5xx Server errors` codes `503 Service Unavailable` fits most naturally however I couldn't find any documentation supporting this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My questions is which HTTP status is most appropriate for an unhealthy application?

[503 Service Unavailable](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-6.6.4), or a lower level [TCP RST](https://www.lovemytool.com/blog/2016/10/tcp-fundamentals-analyzing-tcp-resets-rst-by-chris-greer.html), are perfectly satisfactory ways for a service to announce that it isn't currently available.  You can use [Retry-After](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-7.1.3) if you want to suggest a time to wait.  I haven't seen any documentation suggesting that the ELB client will respect that header.

[GCP](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/health-check-concepts) and [Azure](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/load-balancer/load-balancer-custom-probe-overview) are similar; 200 Healthy, anything else is not.  The Azure document suggests a [500 Internal Server Error](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-6.6.1) as one possible candidate, which is of course fine (Y00 is the coarse grained approximation of all Yxx codes).

The protocol for [Consul checks](https://www.consul.io/docs/agent/checks.html) is similar -- 2xx for healthy, [429 Too Many Requests](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6585#section-4) for a warning (which is a really odd choice), and anything else for failure.

I'm not a big fan of using a [Client Error](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-6.5) to describe what is a server problem; but I don't know that it really hurts anything.  The semantics of `Retry-After` is really only clearly defined for 3xx and 429/503, so if you are hoping to leverage that you should restrict yourself to those codes.

Otherwise, you could dig through the [status code registry](https://www.iana.org/assignments/http-status-codes/http-status-codes.xhtml) to see if there is a code you think is more suitable.